# Using Memcached with Flask Blueprints

Tags: flask, docker-compose, memcached

Within the application context, I can't seem to set objects in memcached. Logs indicate that I connect to memcached, but when I attempt to set an object the set function returns "0" or False. Outside of the application context, I can connect to the server IP and port, and easily get and set objects. Here is my setup:

**application/__init__.py**

```
class App(Flask):

def __init__(self):
    super(App, self).__init__(__name__)
    self.config.from_object('app.config')
    self.config.from_object('app.deployments.Prod')
    logging.basicConfig(filename=self.config['LOG_PATH'] + config.LOG_FILE, level=logging.INFO, format=config.LOG_FORMAT, datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S')
    self.static_folder=config.STATICS
    self.before_request(self.init_dbs)
    self.teardown_request(self.teardown)
    self.after_request(self.teardown)
    try:
        self.init_session()
        self.init_login()
        self.init_templates()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(e)

def init_dbs(self):
    g.ES = init_elasticsearch(hosts=self.config['ES_HOSTS'])
    g.MEMCACHED = init_memcached(host=self.config['MEMCACHED_HOST'],port=self.config['MEMCACHED_PORT'])


...
```

**cache/__init__.py**

```
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import MemcachedCache
import gevent
import logging

def init_memcached(host,port):
    memcached_connected = False
    while not memcached_connected:
        try:
            MEMCACHED = MemcachedCache([host + ':' + str(port)])
            memcached_connected = True
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info("Memcached not connected")
            logging.error(e)
            gevent.sleep(1)
    return MEMCACHED
```

**controllers/page.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, render_template, url_for, flash, g, redirect
from flask.views import MethodView
from flask.ext.login import current_user
from json import dumps
from app import config
...

items = Blueprint(
    'items',
    __name__,
    template_folder=config.TEMPLATES,
)

class Item(MethodView):
    def get(self,item):
        result = g.MEMCACHED.get('item')
        if result is None:
            ...
            g.MEMCACHED.set('item', result, timeout=60)
        return render_template('item.html',result=result)

items.add_url_rule("/path/<item>", view_func=Item.as_view('item'))
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with using memcached within the `g` object. I'd prefer setting the connection to memcached once, as I'm doing with the dbs, but it seems like memcached doesn't respond in the same way.

Comment: Every request push new application context. `g` object is global, but not between requests. [Read the docs about this.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#storing-data)

Comment: Got it. Aside from shifting the implementation to Flask-Cache, do you have a recommendation on what I could do to get this working?

Comment: Flask-Cache is not maintained. Try [Flask-Caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It has enough documentation.

Comment: @Yu Yes, `g` is a per request object, the memcached client is also added to it before every request when @datasci calls `self.before_request(self.init_dbs)`. While I don't know why it does not work, I would not create a new client for each request, but use one global client. On a side note: I would also recommend `Flask-Caching` as it offers many convenience features such as caching decorators and Jinja snippet caching.

Comment: Was an issue with host setup in Docker. Now works fine. Will still explore Flask-Caching.